# SQL Query is not retrieving data

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I am trying to run below query, which successfully run but it does not retrieving any data. I am 100% confident it should retrieve the data as I have manually checked.

What could be the reasons its not working, and any solution?

```
SELECT * FROM REMARKETING D
WHERE D.PNumber NOT IN
(
SELECT P.QNumber FROM POLICY P
)
```

Comment: Qnumber could be null? It could be the issue

Comment: IF Qnumber is null then it should retrieve all the data from Remarketing? right? that's what I want. So currently I can see 92 records in Remarketing DE but after running SQL, the DE is showing 0 record.

Comment: But it is a not IN. Make it in consideration.... If it is a IN, what you are saying would make sense.

Comment: If I will say IN then it will only bring in the matching records. If I will say NOT IN then it will bring in all the non matching records. If I understand correct. And I want to bring in non matching records. So I want to retrieve only Pnumbers those are not found in Qnumber of Policy DE.

Comment: If you test null against anything, it will return true. So, if there is QNumber equal null, your first query will return nothing.

Comment: I was wrong! I made a test and if there is a null value in the subquery, it will return. So, the issue is not the null.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT D.fielda, D.fieldb, D.fieldc 
FROM REMARKETING D
LEFT JOIN POLICY P ON D.pnumber = P.pnumber
WHERE P.pnumber is NULL
```

You'll have to adapt the join to account for what field you're matching on.  You're where statement will give you all the records that are not matched by the join.

Comment: Except you'll need to SELECT explicit fields, so you can't use *

Comment: @MatthewWash That's true -- updating.

Comment: I can not use the join method. And the above query was working perfectly fine until 10/15. Suddenly after 10/15 query retrieve no records.

Comment: Why doesn't the join method work for you?  What type of Query activity are you using?  Are you getting an error message within the Query activity log?

Comment: No i am not getting any error. The query runs successfully. If I will going to join then whole logic will no more work. In Remarketing table their is a Pnumber field in Policy table their are two fields Pnumber and Qnumber.  In policy table when record status change for prospect then a new record created with new Pnumber and old Pnumber goes into Qnumber for the same row.

Comment: Here is what I am trying to achieve. I want to retrieve all the records from Remareketing table where Pnumber is not found under Qnumber in policy table.

Comment: both are valid SQL and should work. I would verify things like field type and data integrity.  I would make sure there are no added spaces or other invisible chars in the fields, that when being compared they are both type INT, and not comparing STRING to INT, etc. I also would try the opposite and do a JOIN to pull in the ones that match. If this works, then you can rule out much of what I said above.